# Change Review Display Name on Woo-commerce Store

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, review

I want to be able to change the name that shows up on the reviews on a woocommerce platform. I have found some information but I am new to WordPress and no one seems to have the answer. Here is a link that I was able to find something but no installation specifics.

I need to know where and how to change this please. Thanks.

Here is the link that I found.

https://silicondales.com/tutorials/woocommerce-tutorials/woocommerce-change-review-author-display-name-username/

I have added a plugin called Username Changer and it let me change the username of the account but it won't update the review username.

Here are some images as of now (3/6/2017)

Snapshot of how user is configured with edited username:

[image: Snapshot of how user is configured with edited username]

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have figured it out. You will need to post the code into the functions.php file if you do not have a child theme. It is recommended that you set one up but I haven't yet and I just wanted to get this fixed first. Here is a snapshot of what you need to too.

Add the below block of text to the bottom or your custom-functions.php or functions.php page within Appearance > Editor

```
add_filter('get_comment_author', 'my_comment_author', 10, 1);
function my_comment_author( $author = '' ) {
// Get the comment ID from WP_Query
$comment = get_comment( $comment_ID );
if (!empty($comment->comment_author) ) {
if($comment->user_id > 0){
$user=get_userdata($comment->user_id);
$author=$user->first_name.' '.substr($user->last_name,0,1).'.'; // this is the actual line you want to change
} else {
$author = __('Anonymous');
}
} else {
$author = $comment->comment_author;
}

return $author;
}
```

Make sure to update the user info.

[Missing Sections from the Original Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbtNp.png)