# How to change the appearance of the name in product reviews "woocommerce"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change the name display in woocommerce product reviews and I use this review plugin, [click](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/reviewx/)

so that it looks like the first name and the letter prefix of the last name

i tried this code in **functions.php**

```
function my_comment_author( $author = '' ) {
// Get the comment ID from WP_Query
$comment = get_comment( $comment_ID );
if (!empty($comment->comment_author) ) {
if($comment->user_id > 0){
$user=get_userdata($comment->user_id);
$author=$user->first_name.' '.substr($user->last_name,0,1).'.'; // this is the actual line you want to change
} else {
$author = __('Anonymous');
}
} else {
$author = $comment->comment_author;
}

return $author;
}
```

but not working

here are some screenshots

[image: 1] [image: 2] [image: 3]

how to do it so it works

Thank you

Comment: Just writing the function won't do anythign you need to find the proper filter

Comment: thanks for the answer, i googled about this problem and i found many, one answer here,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42635460/change-review-display-name-on-woo-commerce-store?rq=1
but so far I haven't succeeded
Can you help me